# Is it possible to create visible documentation for package in go?

Tags: go, godoc

How to create visible Go documentation?

That is easy to create documentation for any function in go like that:

```golang
package main

// documentation example
func DocumentedFunction() bool {
    return true
}
```

And i can see that documentation when i call that function:

[image]

Can i write package documentation, that will be visible from editor/IDE? Do i have to install additional tools to achieve similar behaviour for package documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official Go documentation](https://go.dev/blog/godoc) and [this link](https://yourbasic.org/golang/package-documentation/), it should be possible to create documentation for an entire package the same way you would do it for a function:

> To document a function, type, constant, variable, or even a complete package, write a regular comment directly preceding its declaration, with no blank line in between.

For example: the [strings](https://pkg.go.dev/strings) package:

```
// Package strings implements simple functions to manipulate UTF-8 encoded strings.
//
// For information about UTF-8 strings in Go, see  https://blog.golang.org/strings.
package strings
..
..
rest of the file
```

So you basically just add a normal comment above the `package` keyword.

Comment: A more authoritative source is https://go.dev/blog/godoc. It also explains how to handle a large amount of package documentation.

Comment: @Peter thanks, I'll update the link!

Comment: is that an IDE problem that i do not recieve package documentation from outside the package when i import that? example (documentation in package is provided): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dancheg97/Dancheg97/main/package.png

Comment: @DanilaFomin which IDE is this?

Comment: @matkv this is VSCode